# Hibernate using C3P0 Works fine on Oracle but does not close connection with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, servlets

I am using Servlet 2.4, Hibernate 4.2.4 Final, c3p0 0.9.2.1, Tomcat 7.0.42, MySQL 5.6 & JSP.

I had completed development using Oracle 11gR2 DB but at a later point was asked to switch to MySQL as the Database.

I have a rather unusual problem at hand.

The problem is **Multiple MySQL Process/Connections being created for every single DB request**, which are neither closed nor returned to the pool despite issuing the `SessionFactoryUtil.close();` which was not the case with Oracle DB.

I tested the exact same code on these two different Databases, i.e after executing a Function/Request (ex: Login)

The application when tested with Oracle (11gR2) the DB created a single connection and used it for all requests henceforth. 
`SELECT * FROM V$RESOURCE_LIMIT`
Gives me the following Output
RESOURCE_NAME: processes
CURRENT_UTILIZATION: 32
MAX_UTILIZATION: 36
INITIAL_ALLOCATION: 300
LIMIT_VALUE: 300
No matter how many users log in the Connection pool maintains it gracefully.

Now on the other hand when the same application was run on MySQL:
I did a `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on MySQL which shows two processes being created for every request; c3p0 successfully terminates one connection but the other connection remains till the DB crashes because it exceeded the max connections available.

My SessionFactoryUtil is quite simple and straightforward and is as follows:
`public class SessionFactoryUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;`

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();//deprecated method not changed due to official reason
}

public Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public static void close() {
    if (sessionFactory != null) {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
    sessionFactory = null;
}
```

My DAO Method is as follows

```
public User getUserByName(String userName) throws FetchException {
User user = null;
Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    user = (User) session.createQuery("from User where userName = '" + userName + "'").uniqueResult();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("UserDaoImpl -> getUserByName() : Error : " +e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    SessionFactoryUtil.close();
}
return user;
```

The stack trace where c3p0 destroys a connection is as follows:

`20:45:43,692  INFO com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool:1493 - A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@61f31fff
20:45:43,692  INFO com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool:1496 - Logging the stack trace by which the overdue resource was checked-out.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:555)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.demo.access.impl.ConfDaoImp.showAllEvents(ConfDaoImp.java:939)
    at com.demo.business.impl.ConfServiceImpl.showAllEvents(ConfServiceImpl.java:404)
    at com.demo.controller.UserController.getControls(UserController.java:112)
    at com.demo.controller.UserController.validateUser(UserController.java:93)
    at com.demo.controller.UserController.process(UserController.java:42)
    at com.demo.controller.ApplicationServlet.process(ApplicationServlet.java:75)
    at com.demo.controller.ApplicationServlet.doPost(ApplicationServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.demo.controller.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

I have read almost all the question related to this particular scenario but none seems to work, or the thread was abandoned half way, or I am missing out something; could some one please help me get through with this.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of your code did the trick for me:

```
public static void close() {
if(sessionFactory instanceof SessionFactoryImpl) {
      SessionFactoryImpl sf = (SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory;
      ConnectionProvider conn = sf.getConnectionProvider();
      if(conn instanceof C3P0ConnectionProvider) { 
        ((C3P0ConnectionProvider)conn).close(); 
      }
   }
sessionFactory.close(); }
```

Until then Tomcat had (correctly) complained about memory leaks at each hot deployment. Thanks!

Comment: Just a little note: C3P0ConnectionProvider.close() is deprecated, use close() instead.

Comment: @James "... close() is deprecated, use close() instead". On which object?

Comment: Sorry, I meant stop() on the same object. ((C3P0ConnectionProvider)conn).stop();

Answer (score 0):

a few ideas:

1) you are never closing the Session you create (implicitly by asking for a "current session"). that's a straightforward reason why you might have an unreturned Connection that eventually times out.

2) you are treating your SessionFactory like a Session, building up then tearing down the whole thing (which includes a Connection pool) just to get and use one Connection. not so good. your SessionFamily should have a long lifecycle, your sessions should be for one-time, short-term use.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Steve. I agree with your comments, i will close each session and get back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I found out the answer to my strange problem and I thought that sharing it would help most.

To start with, A couple of things i did wrong was...
 
Firstly, I migrated from hibernate 3.6 to 4.2 and on doing so I was still using the deprecated `buildSessionFactory()` method.

Secondly, I was using `SessionFactoryUtil.close()` after the end of each query statement in my DAO, which defeats the purpose of using *Connection Pooling.*

Finally, The strange issue where Oracle seems to close the connection successfully after execution of a statement whereas MySql was unable to close the same still remains a mystery.
This, I suspect happened because I was asking SessionFactoryUtil to close a connection which was originally opened by C3P0ConnectionProvider (which I believe was in-turn causing the connection leaks).

After a lot of research and looking around I re-wrote the SessionFactoryUtil as follows...

```
public class SessionFactoryUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static Session getCurrentSession() {
    if(sessionFactory == null){
        getSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public static void close() {
    if(sessionFactory instanceof SessionFactoryImpl) {
          SessionFactoryImpl sf = (SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory;
          ConnectionProvider conn = sf.getConnectionProvider();
          if(conn instanceof C3P0ConnectionProvider) { 
            ((C3P0ConnectionProvider)conn).close(); 
          }
       }
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

Note that all my connections are opened by *C3P0ConnectionProvider* so it is only logical to close it using *C3P0ConnectionProvider* itself.

The following is my hibernate.cfg.xml along with c3p0 settings.

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/application</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>

     <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

     <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>

    <!-- Create or update the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

    <!-- DEPRECATED -->
    <!--        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> -->
    <!-- C3p0 connection pooling configuration -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">600</property>
    <property name="c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">false</property>
    <!--        configuration pool via c3p0    -->
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>   
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">600</property>    
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">75</property>   
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">5</property>   
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>   
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">600</property>
    <property name="c3p0.checkoutTimeout">6000000</property>

    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>   

    <!-- Mapping -->

</session-factory>
```

This is again one of the methods from my DAO Class...

```
public User getUserByName(String userName) throws FetchException {
User user = null;
Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getCurrentSession();
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    user = (User) session.createQuery("from User where userName = '" + userName + "'").uniqueResult();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("UserDaoImpl -> getUserByName() : Error : " +e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

}
return user;
```

Note that in my DAO at the finally block i don't have to close my connection any more I let c3p0 handle the connection pool.

And voila...!! The Application runs!!! Had more than 2000 transaction hits on a single day in a span of 2 hours.
I hope this helps noob hibernate users like me.